# How to use Robot framework to write Get adb log after Enter Ctrl+c to automatically execute the function in Terminal and Windows CMD?

Tags: robotframework

How to use Robot framework to write Record 15 secs Android adb log after enter Ctrl+c to automatically execute the function in Terminal and Windows CMD??

adb shell logcat -b crash > log_carsh_date.txt
Record 15 secs
Enter Ctrl+c

Can you help me? Thank you.

```
 ${result} =     Run     adb shell logcat -b crash > log_carsh_date202221027.txt
    Sleep   15s
    AutoItLibrary.Send {^c}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `OperatingSystem.Run` you most probably would be better served by using `Run Process` keyword from [Process Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process). You can see there the arguments for capturing the output directly and setting a timeout.

I have never used logcat but the command would probably look something like this

```py
${result}=    Run Process    adb shell logcat -b crash > log_carsh_date202221027.txt    timeout=15s
```

The `${result}` is a result object, which you can get different properties out of after the run as explained [in the documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object).

Comment: Thanks for your help. How about this timeout=15s after [Enter Ctrl+c] ? How write Robot framework for [Enter Ctrl+c] at Terminal and Windows CMD?

Comment: Is the button combination doing something other than interrupting the process? If not, the timeout is there to do that. If the button combination activates some function, see keyword [Send Signal to Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Send%20Signal%20To%20Process).

Comment: Not a key combination. It's combination key (Ctrl + C) to interrupt the process at Terminal or Windows CMD. Understood. Will try add this timeout=15s to see if it's work or not. Thanks your help.

Comment: Thanks for your (Morkkis) help. I have tried to add this timeout=15s, and then it's work at present.